# Get the total male and total female users that did not place an order for a product

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get the total female, total male and (SUM of both male and female users that did not place an order for a products. The results should look like this:

```
total male     | total female     | total
---------------------------------------
 31            |      24          |  55
---------------------------------------
```

Fiddle to help http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a0e30/36

Previous code:

```
select p.*,
   (select count(*)
    from users u 
    where u.uid not in (select o.uid from       orders o where o.productid = p.productid) and 
          u.gender = 'Male'
   ) as NumMales,
   (select count(*)
    from users u 
    where u.uid not in (select o.uid from orders o where o.productid = p.productid) and 
          u.gender = 'Female'
   ) as NumFemales
```

from products p ;

Comment: I misunderstood your question, i just updated my answer to get those numbers shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I miss understood your question at first, I thought you were trying to get count of users, it turns out your trying to count possible orders for products for each person that haven't been placed.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'Male' THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END) as Male,
       SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'Female' THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END) as Female,
       COUNT(1) as Total
FROM Users U INNER JOIN Products P
LEFT JOIN Orders O ON O.uid = U.uid AND P.productid = O.productid
WHERE O.uid IS NULL
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a0e30/65)
    And this query returns the same result as your previous query but not using IN clause so it might be faster.

```
SELECT P.productid,P.productname,P.productdescription,
       SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'Male' THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END) as Male,
       SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'Female' THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END) as Female,
       COUNT(1) as Total
FROM Users U INNER JOIN Products P
LEFT JOIN Orders O ON O.uid = U.uid AND P.productid = O.productid
WHERE O.uid IS NULL
GROUP BY P.productid,P.productname,P.productdescription
```